# ng7 -> дочерний модуль вызывает рендер родительского

Tags: angular2

есть два модуля:

- рут  (app-root)
- часы (app-clock)

часы раз в секунду обновляют переменную `date`

вопрос номер раз:
можно ли отключить "наблюдение всех элементов" компонента ?

вопрос номер два:
как правильно реализовать не используя RxJS ?

вопрос номер три:
почему обновление в дочернем компоненте, вызывает обновление родителя ? 
(см. `console.count('RootComponent: qwa');`)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: `
        {{ qwa }}<br /><app-clock></app-clock>
    `
})
export class AppComponent {
    get qwa() {
        console.count('RootComponent: qwa');
        return 'qwa';
    }
}
```

---

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-clock',
    template: `
        <span>{{ Time }}</span> <br />
        <span> {{ Date }}</span>
    `
})
export class ClockComponent {
    interval = null;
    date: Date = new Date();
    get Time() {
        return this.date.toLocaleTimeString();
    }
    get Date() {
        return this.date.toLocaleDateString();
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.interval = setInterval(this.tic.bind(this), 1e3);
    }
    ngOnDestroy() {
        clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
    tic() {
        console.log('ClockComponent: tic');
        this.date = new Date();
    }
}
```

живой пример (ng5, не виснет, в консоле можно наблюдать `console.count`)
https://y2oy31kxpv.codesandbox.io/

ссылка на код к примеру (**вешает вкладку**, если сразу не закрыть просмотр )
https://codesandbox.io/s/y2oy31kxpv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `можно ли отключить "наблюдение всех элементов" компонента` - вопрос непонятен
2. `как правильно реализовать не используя RxJS ?` - что именно реализовать? :)
3. `почему обновление в дочернем компоненте, вызывает обновление родителя ?` - потому что механизм обнаружения изменений продвигается только вперед и никогда не оглядывается назад, начиная с корневого (рут) компонента до последнего. В этом и есть смысл одностороннего потока данных. Архитектура Angular приложения очень проста — дерево компонентов. Каждый компонент указывает на дочерний, но дочерний не указывает на родительский. Односторонний поток устраняет необходимость $digest цикла, как это было в Angular 1.x

Comment: мне тут подсказали, что первые два вопроса решаются https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef, но основной - третий.

Comment: ссылка на вьюху (CDR) никак не решит ваш вопрос :))

Comment: (потому что механизм обнаружения изменений продвигается только вперед ... начиная с корневого (рут) компонента до последнего) то есть на каждый "рендер" или изменение переменной ангуляр проходит всё дерево?

Comment: не на каждый "рендер", а на любое асинхронное событие, да, проходит все дерево

Comment: если вам интересно как это работает - советую прочитать https://medium.com/@overthesanity/zone-js-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D1%8F-fdb995917968